# Is it possible to provide a runtime value to StringLength validator in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I'm validating a field in MVC 3 with data annotations:

```
[StringLength(50, MinimumLength=5)]
public string MyText { get; set; }
```

Is there a way to provide a dynamic value there?  Something like this:

```
[StringLength(50, MinimumLength=GetMinimumLengthValueFromDb())]
public string MyText { get; set; }
```

My last resort is to use remote validator. If I won't find a way to do this with `StringLength`, I will use `RemoteValidator`.

Comment: I'd extend the StringLenghtAttribute class, overriding just the constructor to retrieve defaults from db.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, only compile time values, like constants, can be provided for attributes. This limitation applies to all C# attributes and is not specific to data annotation attributes, but in the case of the `StringLengthAttribute` implies that there is way to provide a different length at runtime.

You'll need to use another kind of validation or maybe create a custom attribute inheriting from `StringLengthAttribute` that accepts a `Type` and the name of a method on that type as the source for the length value. This approach would be similar to the one used by [`CustomValidationAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute.method.aspx) that accepts a `ValidatorType` and a `Method` name as sources for the validation.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented validation in the way you described - inherited from StringLengthAttribute and localized it and added logic for picking custom min length value from DB

Comment: Thanks for pointing at the `CustomValidationAttribute`! I had totally forgotten about that :-)

Comment: @valerii.sverdlik: Is it perhaps possible to share the code you used?